# How can use Scrollbar in android in this case?

Tags: android, xml, scrollbar

in an XML file, I have 4 tablelayouts in which the rows are being created dynamically when the user inputs an item. however i want to give each table a specific space of the UI and then just have a scrollbar in each table in case there are too many items in each table.
How can i do that please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/loggedas" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="346dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="82dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loggedastoedit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="138dp"
    android:layout_y="0dp"
    android:text="@string/loggedas"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="1dp"
    android:layout_y="15dp"
    android:text="@string/youneed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caloriesneeded"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="66dp"
    android:layout_y="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/Red" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="146dp"
    android:layout_y="17dp"
    android:text="@string/caloriestextfield" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="191dp"
    android:layout_y="17dp"
    android:text="@string/today" />



<TableLayout

    android:id="@+id/breakfasttableviewing"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="1dp"
    android:layout_y="62dp" >

</TableLayout>




<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/lunchtableviewing"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="2dp"
    android:layout_y="135dp" >

</TableLayout>


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/dinnertableviewing"
    android:layout_width="346dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="2dp"
    android:layout_y="210dp" >

</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addexercisebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="373dp"
    android:text="@string/addexercise" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addmealbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="121dp"
    android:layout_y="373dp"
    android:text="@string/addfood" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newday"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="209dp"
    android:layout_y="373dp"
    android:text="@string/newday" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="111dp"
    android:layout_y="43dp"
    android:text="@string/breakfast"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_x="120dp"
    android:layout_y="107dp"
    android:text="@string/lunch"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="121dp"
    android:layout_y="184dp"
    android:text="@string/dinner"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="116dp"
    android:layout_y="265dp"
    android:text="@string/exercise"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/exercisetableviewing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="5dp"
    android:layout_y="289dp" >
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: AbsoluteLayouts are frowned upon since they don't display in a predictable manner on different devices, so I would recommend a different layout, like the RelativeLayout, without all the Space elements. To make your TableLayouts scroll with fling gestures responses wrap each TableLayout in a ScrollView.

Comment: what is the advantage of RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each tableView with `ScrollView`, and set on each ScrollView `android:layout_weight` property to divide the screen among them with proportions you desire;